# When tables from HTML are converted to pdf using jspdf,table borders are not drawn properly when the page breaks

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, jspdf, html2canvas

I am trying to print different tables from HTML to pdf using jspdf.

While drawing borders(right and left) which is done by `html2canvas.js` file when the height of a particular tables exceeds the page size it does not split the table border at a right place.It tries to draw the line by picking the coordinates from the next table.

I need continue to draw the line in the next page from where the page actually starts.  Do not know where to stop drawing the line when the page breaks and draw the remaining part from the next page.

Comment: Please provide us with code samples of what you tried until now. That way we can help you more effectively.

Comment: html2pdf($htmlPage.body, pdf, function(){})

Comment: html2pdf($htmlPage.body, pdf, function(){}) - Here the $htmlPage.body have different tables.While converting to pdf it calculates the borders for it to draw lines NodeParser.prototype.parseBorders in html2canvas.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is not exactly what you are looking for, but maybe it can help you.

I had a similar problem. I was trying to use html2canvas and jsPDF to create tables with multiple pages. But it was pretty annoying. html2canvas don't have a good resolution. Besides, it is hard to set the image size in jsPDF.

Then I just have used the autoTable plugin (https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable)

Basically, if my table is big and need more than 1 page, I just divide it in piecewises, one piece per page.

Here how it looks like

[MultipleTablePDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvjWT.png)